# Does NOR flash wear occur when rewriting a bit to its same value?

Tags: embedded, memory, flash, nor-flash

The obvious answer is no. Wear is caused by discharging a memory cell (bit). If the cell is a 1 and you write a 1, the cell does not get discharged. If the cell is zero and you write a zero, the cell cannot be discharged further.

Is this reasoning correct, or can wear still occur when writing the same value again to a bit?

If it matters, I'm working with the IS25WP064A_032A family of NOR flash chips.

Comment: It depends. If you have to change other bits in the same block, it will have to get erased anyway. So if it's a 0 (1 is the erased state), it'll get the wear from being erased and re-written.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, for a programming operation (going from a 1 to a zero), NOR flash chips have a granularity of 1 bit. So, as long as the bit you are trying to write can be written to the value you are writing without an erase, other bits should not be affected. @Hearth

Comment: However, this still relies on my question. In this flash chip, and all others I've seen, when you program you are sending a command for a whole byte (or more). However, in theory, flash chips have bit-wise granularity. So when I send a whole byte to change a single bit, is it the case that only the bit that I'm targeting experiences wear? Of course, in this case, all other bits will be set to the same value currently on the flash memory as to not cause them to change state and induce wear.